# How to Transform Observable<Observable<List<T>>> to Observable<List<T>>

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am stuck on how to convert/transform the following observable type to my target type:

I have observable of type:

```
Observable<Observable<List<FooBar>>>
```

I want to convert it to:

```
Observable<List<FooBar>>
```

So when I subscribe on it, it emits `List<FooBar>` not `Observable<List<FooBar>>`

I tried with map, flatMap... I could not find a solution.

However, I found a strange looking operator called `blockingFirst` which my IDE indicates that it returns `Observable<List<FooBar>>` when applied to `Observable<Observable<List<FooBar>>>`

But the 'blocking' part is confusing me.

I am also looking for better solution than `blockingFirst` one, if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flatMap` is indeed the way to go:

```
Observable<Observable<List<FooBar>>> streamOfStreams = ...
Observable<List<FooBar>> listStream = 
          streamOfStreams.flatMap(listObservable -> listObservable);
```

I think you should look at it in a different perspective, it is not simple converting from 1 type to another type. `Observable` of `Observables` means stream that emit streams that each of them emit a list of some items. what you want to achieve is to flatten it to single stream that emit all the lists from all the streams.
 `flatMap` doing it exactly, you give it an item emission, and return an `Observable`, `flatMap` will subscribe to the returned `Observable` and will merge each item emitted from it to the source stream, in this case, as you simply return each item emission which is `Observable<List<FooBar>>`, you practically taking each emitted `Observable` , subscribe to it, and merge all its list emissions back, so you get back stream of all the lists from all the `Observables`.

`blockingFirst` is definitely not the way to go, what it does is to wait (block) until first emission and return this item only, as your items ar `Observable<List<FooBar>>` you'll get the only first `Observable`. so while it indeed has the same type, its clearly not the same stream you want.