# Type Observable<Observable<any[]>> is not assignable to type Observable<any[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am implementing autocomplete with data from database service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SchoolService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  getSchools(): Observable<School[]> {
    return this.db.collection<School>('schools').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

In my component:

```
export class SchoolComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  schools: Observable<School[]>;
  filteredSchools: Observable<School[]>;

  constructor(private schoolService: SchoolService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.schools = this.schoolService.getSchools();

    //Below line gives error "Type Observable<Observable<School[]>> is not assignable to type Observable<School[]>".
    this.filteredSchools = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(name => this.filterSchools(name))
    );
  }

  filterSchools(name: string): Observable<School[]> {
    return this.schools.map(school => school.filter(s => s.name.toLowerCase().includes(name)));
  }
}
```

And my html:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Type Your School to Continue" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           [formControl]="formControl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let school of filteredSchools | async" [value]="school">
        <span>{{school.name}}</span> |
        <small>{{school.city}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The function in `ngOnInit` gives `Type Observable<Observable<School[]>> is not assignable to type Observable<School[]>` error. How can I fix this?

Comment: why dont use a subscribe pattern like this https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables_from_other_sources.html

Comment: @Eldho The documentation says Observable will work if I use `async` in `mat-option *ngFor` so I don't need to use `subscribe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Transform Observable<Observable<List<T>>> to Observable<List<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712065/how-to-transform-observableobservablelistt-to-observablelistt)

Comment: @Eldho https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

Comment: @ibenjelloun Hello, can you please remove the duplicate flag? My question is different though the title looks similar.

Comment: `filterSchools` returns an `Observable` that is mapped to `Observable<Observable<>>` in the `map(name => this.filterSchools(name))`, I think its a duplicate, you just need to use the right rxjs function to merge your Observables, flatMap or combineLatest... depending on your needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error says exactly what's wrong. You defined:

```
filteredSchools: Observable<School[]>;
```

but later you create an Observable that emits (maps each value) results of `filterSchools(name: string): Observable<School[]>` which returns an Observable as well so at the end you have an Observable chain of `Observable<Observable<School[]>>`.

It actually looks like you just wanted to use `switchMap` (or `mergeMap` or `concatMap`) instead of `map`. `switchMap` will subscribe to the nested Observable and turn the chain into `Observable<School[]>`:

```
this.filteredSchools = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  switchMap(name => this.filterSchools(name))
);
```

Comment: Thanks. You enlightened me. In my case, `switchMap` (not `mergeMap`) works with the typeahead feature in autocomplete. Can you please update your answer before I accept it?

Comment: Ok, just be aware that `switchMap` isn't exactly the same as `mergeMap` even when it solves your problem but maybe it doesn't matter in your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Observable.combineLatest(...)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.schools = this.schoolService.getSchools();

   this.filteredSchools = Observable.combineLatest(
      this.formControl.valueChanges.startWith(''),
      this.schools
   ).map(([filter, schools]) => {
       if (!filter || filter === '') {
          return schools;
       }

       return schools.filter(s => s.name.toLowerCase().includes(name));
   });
}
```

Still having a cold observable at the end, will only be triggered when one of the observables are emitting new data.

Not your question but for your templates autocomplete you will need a [displayWith](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reminding me to use `displayWith` function. :)